# How can I animate the error label with jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-animate

This seems like a very simple question, but I think hours of staring at code has made me struggle to find a solution

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plug-in](http://bassistance.de/2011/05/14/release-validation-plugin-1-8-1/) & I want animate the display of the error label. Is is possible? If so how?

I have had a look around but the solution appears to be alluding me!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: animate how/in what way?

Comment: just to change the opacity and prehaps utilise a slide or one of the easing options....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
$("#yourform").validate({
rules: {  

Your rules

 },
 messages:{

Your messages

 },
 errorPlacement: function(error, element){
 if ( element.is(":radio") || element.is(":checkbox")){
error.insertAfter(element.parent()).animate({opacity: 0.25, left: '+=50'});
} else { 
error.insertAfter(element).animate({opacity: 0.25, left: '+=50'});
}
   }

});
```

Comment: AR, your a star! implemented the code & it works perfectly. Just a few tweaks to get the style I'm after. Really surprised I couldn't find the answer myself!!!

Thanks again

Comment: Is there a more commonly accepted way to do this now? This method has several shortcomings because the function is only run once, not each time the field is validated....

Answer (score 5):

Previous answer is not fully correct.

The `errorPlacement` function is called only once for each error. If you toggle this error on and off - jquery.validate calls just `hide` and `show` and `highlight` and `unhighlight`.

So you need two additions:

Firstly add animation to highlight option:

```
 highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parent().find('.help-block') //your error placement
       .slideDown(300); //animation
 }
```

Secondly, if you want animation for hide message, you can't use 'unhighlight' and 'slideUp', because jquery.validate directly calls 'hide' before you animation completes.

So you need override standard jquery.validate logic:

```
jQuery.validator.prototype.hideErrors = function() {
     this.addWrapper( this.toHide ).slideUp(300);
}
```